# Display divs , side by side in percentage and side margins?

Tags: css, css-float

Is there any way to get the following box model to work. 
I have 2 div's in a container that should be displayed side by side. 
The problem I have is that I must push the left div by certain number
Also trying to stay away from negative margin on right div because it is 
braking  the responsive layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ubg6H/1/

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box_in">Sample</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box_in">Sample</div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box_in">Sample</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


#header {
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:15px;
}
#left, #right {
    display:table;
    background:green;
    height:200px;
}
#left {
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#right {
    width:80%;
    float:right;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.box {
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
}
.box_in {
    background:red;
    margin:10px;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution

http://jsfiddle.net/Ubg6H/6/

use

```
display:table;
```

and

```
display:table-cell;
```

Thnx to

http://mihaifrentiu.com/how-to-fill-the-available-space-when-using-floated-divs

Comment: Oh I see what you meant now. Well, I'm happy you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is reduce the width of your right div and it will slide up to be side by side. I think you have a few other things you should probably rework to work well responsively. But anyways the problem is there isn't space for both divs to fit side by side currently. So you can fix it by reducing margin or reducing width.

Edit:
I'm definitely not into magic numbers, but as CodeMonkeyG said, there is a difference between magic numbers and mathematics. You could however use the css calc to calculate the difference. So for example: you would have the percentage be the fluid width and the 80px be what ever your fix margin and padding would equal.

```
width: calc(100% - 80px);
```

You can also choose to do percentage based margins and padding if you so desire. Calc is probably going to give you better control though. Unless you plan on continuing with some media queries.

Comment: cmon , that is not what Im trying to do. need the box model fix not magic numbers

Comment: @Benn what you are asking for would be impossible even mathematically. If the width of 2 divs combined == 100% of their container, any amount of margin or padding will break the second div into a new line. You must either decrease margins or decrease the width of your divs so that combined they are all <= 100% of the container's width. There is no box model fix to be had here.

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
#right {
width:77%;
float:right;
margin-left:10px;}
```

The #right{width:80%;} is too much with the margin so it moved #right below the left div

http://jsfiddle.net/Ubg6H/3/